# Method call with an argument of type array with a valueRank > 1 fails with 'BadInvalidArgument'

Tags: javascript, node.js, opc-ua, node-opcua

I'm using [node-opcua](https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua) to create an opc-ua server using node.js.

On the server-side, I register a method that has an 2-Dimensional Array as an input argument. When browsing the server from a client like [UaExpert](https://www.unified-automation.com/products/development-tools/uaexpert.html), I see the method with a proper descriptions of the arguments. I can set the argument-values from the client, but calling the method just fails with a `BadInvalidArgument` exception.

As soon as I change the dimension of the array to 1 (by setting `valueRank` to 1), everything works as expected.

I'm following the minimal sample from node-opcua on [server-methods](https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua/blob/master/documentation/server_with_method.md):

```
const { 
    OPCUAServer,
    DataType,
    Variant,VariantArrayType,
    StatusCodes,
    makeAccessLevelFlag 
} = require("node-opcua");

(async () => {
    try {
        const server = new OPCUAServer({
            port: 4334 // the port of the listening socket of the server
        });
        
        
        await server.initialize();
        
        const addressSpace = server.engine.addressSpace;
        const namespace = addressSpace.getOwnNamespace();
        
        const myDevice = namespace.addObject({
            organizedBy: addressSpace.rootFolder.objects,
            browseName: "MyDevice"
        });
        
        //_"adding a method on the device object"
        const method = namespace.addMethod(myDevice,{

            browseName: "Bark",
        
            inputArguments:  [
                {
                    name:"nbBarks",
                    description: { text: "specifies the number of time I should bark" },
                    dataType: DataType.Int32,
                    valueRank: 2,
                    arrayDimensions: [2, 2]
                }
             ],
        
            outputArguments: [{
                 name:"Barks",
                 description:{ text: "the generated barks" },
                 dataType: DataType.UInt32,
                 valueRank: -1
            }]
        });        
        
        //_"binding the method with your own function"
        method.bindMethod((inputArguments,context,callback) => {
       
            const callMethodResult = {
                statusCode: StatusCodes.Good,
                outputArguments: [{
                        dataType: DataType.String,
                        arrayType: VariantArrayType.Array,
                        value :99
                }]
            };
            callback(null,callMethodResult);
        });        

        await server.start();
        console.log("Server is now listening ... ( press CTRL+C to stop)");
        const endpointUrl = server.endpoints[0].endpointDescriptions()[0].endpointUrl;
        console.log(" the primary server endpoint url is ", endpointUrl );        
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})();
```

Here is a screenshot before calling the method from UaExpert:

[image: Calling method bark]

It seems the client correctly recognizes the argument as an array with the dimension [2x2]. But when calling the method, I just get a `BadInvalidArgument` exception on the client-side.

Any hints what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a bug in the node-opcua stack.

Comment: Thanks, I'll open a corresponding issue.

Comment: Thank you, this is now fixed in node-opcua@2.70.0